# How to make vmware provide multiple virtual network interfaces?

Tags: vmware, network-interface

As we know by default there's only a `eth0`,how to make it provide another interface to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VmWare Virtual Network Editor, which is installed with the most VmWare Products like Workstation.

Comment: Yeah I know that menu,but seems it can't place a new network interface in the `vkm` OS,it only places a new virtual adapter on the hosting OS.